# Dropbox list_folder call doesn't work in PHP_cURL

Tags: php, dropbox-api, php-curl

I'm trying to detect all of the subfolders in a given directory, using the PHP_CURL library to interact with the Dropbox API. I think this is just a syntax issue, with the JSON body of the call, but I don't know what's wrong.

```
$url = "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder";

$data = array('path' => '/root/folder');
$post_body = json_encode($data);

print_r( $post_body );

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $token,
                                           'Content-Type: application/json') );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_body); 


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
curl_close($ch); 

print_r($data);
```

Here is the output:

```
{"path":"\/root\/folder"}
```

There are definitely folders in that directory, but nothing beyond my debug shows up when I run this from command line-- no errors, or anything. It also works just fine when I run it with Postman. Meanwhile, my file-upload testing script works perfectly, so I know there's no problem with my authorization token.

Why is my code broken?

Answer (score 0):

The correct API URL for listing the subfolders is:

https://**api.**dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder

I copy/pasted the file-upload URL, which was:

https://**content.**dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder

So it was a syntax error, just not where I was looking for it.